# Django custom template filter feeding cookie or default value

Tags: django

I'm designing a custom django filter, just to make sure it works I have something like this

```
{{ "Sleeps:"|translate:"fr" }}
```

and it works.

Now in the final implementation, I want it to get a cookie or else use a default value

```
{{ pg.title|translate:request.COOKIES.lang|default:"en" }}
```

I'm getting this error

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /chalet/belle-chery
Failed lookup for key [lang] in {'_ga': 'GA1.1.1026479868.1547798010', 'cookie-policy': 'true', 'csrftoken': 'VrVrvgZUfFrWhFDFjLIvZgOus9NrmjDx1JwNP2lzvz2FRAGmC1lLrKwiH4g31X5F', 'sessionid': 'ptp6smvt9w95qtqlkc7klx736u5k7uu5'}
```

so it doesn't implement the default part.

So I figure there's either a way to fix this or use middleware to set the cookie if it's not set.

Would be nice if it doesn't need middleware.

Comment: A template filter can only take one explicit parameter. If you however will always use `request.COOKIES.lang`, then you can "hardcode" this.

Comment: The `default:` is thus *not* allied to the `request.COOKIES.lang`, but to the result of `pg.title|translate:...`.

Answer (score 0):

> so it doesn't implement the default part.

It does, it applies the `|default:"en"` filter to the *result* of `{{ pg.title|translate:request.COOKIES.lang }}`, not to the `request.COOKIES.lang` expression.

The easiest way to solve this is probably defining a local variable, for example with the [**`{% with ... %}`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag:

```
{% with lang=request.COOKIES.lang|default:"en" %}
    {{ pg.title|translate:lang }}
{% endwith %}
```